# Best way to diagnose and repair ruby gem errors on mac

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

(Edited to include full error msg)

All of a sudden *any* `gem` command throws the following error:

> /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0/psych-2.0.6/psych.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
>   ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
>
> -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
>
> See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
>        * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>        * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>        * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
>        * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
>      the more detail of.
>
> -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
>
> c:0014 p:-17529742134590 s:0075 e:000074 TOP    [FINISH]
>
> c:0013 p:---- s:0073 e:000072 CFUNC  :require
>   c:0012 p:0115 s:0069 e:000068 METHOD /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
>   c:0011 p:0007 s:0059 e:000058 TOP    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:1 [FINISH]
>   c:0010 p:---- s:0057 e:000056 CFUNC  :require
>   c:0009 p:0115 s:0053 e:000052 METHOD /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
>   c:0008 p:0078 s:0043 e:000042 METHOD /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:601
>   c:0007 p:0013 s:0039 e:000038 METHOD /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:328
>   c:0006 p:0145 s:0033 e:000032 METHOD /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197 [FINISH]
>   c:0005 p:---- s:0022 e:000021 CFUNC  :new
>   c:0004 p:0018 s:0018 e:000016 METHOD /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74
>   c:0003 p:0018 s:0013 e:000012 METHOD /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39
>   c:0002 p:0115 s:0007 E:0015e0 EVAL   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/bin/gem:21 [FINISH]
>   c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000278 TOP    [FINISH]
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in`run'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in`new'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:328:in`load_file'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:601:in `load_yaml'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:1:in`'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>
> -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
>
> -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
>
> - Loaded script: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/bin/gem
> - Loaded features:
>
>   0 enumerator.so
>     1 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/enc/encdb.bundle
>     2 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
>     3 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/rbconfig.rb
>     4 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
>     5 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
>     6 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
>     7 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
>     8 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
>     9 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
>     10 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
>     11 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
>     12 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
>     13 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
>     14 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
>     15 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
>     16 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
>     17 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
>     18 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
>     19 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
>     20 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
>     21 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/optparse.rb
>     22 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/io/console.bundle
>     23 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
>     24 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command.rb
>     25 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb
>     26 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/etc.bundle
>     27 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
>     28 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
>     29 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
>     30 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb
>
> [NOTE]
>   You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
>   Bug reports are welcome.
>   For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
>
> Abort trap: 6

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you add the rest of the error? Not enough info here.

Comment: Uh-huh. Did you upgrade to Yosemite? Did you reinstall Xcode?

Comment: I have not upgraded or reinstalled Xcode. Actually, checking the app/updates it appears my Xcode was updated. However I have not upgraded to Yosemite.

Comment: Try accepting the Xcode license agreement, installing the command line tools again, and then re-installing Ruby and/or recompiling gems with native extensions.

Comment: @Ken Glad I could help. I've posted the solution as an answer so that you have something to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments, the OP said:

> Actually, checking the app/updates it appears my Xcode was updated. However I have not upgraded to Yosemite.

Upgrades to Apple's [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) can break things in surprising ways. Whenever Xcode is updated, or OS X system libraries are upgraded, it can often help to do some or all of the following:

1. Accept the new Xcode license agreement. You need to do this after each upgrade, even if you've accepted the agreement before.
2. Installing the Xcode command line tools again.
3. Re-install any non-system Ruby versions, and recompile gems with native extensions.